# Bootstrap 3 flex box issue with columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I seem to be having an issue trying to use flexbox with bootstrap 3 columns.
I have the below code which can be previewed [on jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nV3Ua/3652/)

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 widget-header-item">
    <div class="panel panel-primary pmd-z-depth">
        <div class="panel-heading">Box 1</div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="col-md-12 text-left">
                <tr>
                    <td>Key</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Key</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                        <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Key</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 widget-header-item">
    <div class="panel panel-primary pmd-z-depth">
        <div class="panel-heading">Box 2</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
           <table class="col-md-12 text-left">
                <tr>
                    <td>Key</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 widget-header-item">
    <div class="panel panel-primary pmd-z-depth">
        <div class="panel-heading">Box 3</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.widget-header-div, .widget-header-div > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

I have tried a few different css snippets but I either end up with equal width column which i do not want as i want col-xs-* to persist or I can get equals heights but again it throws the widths off.

What I am trying to achieve is equal height for all 3 panels but the column widths from the classes to be taken into account.

Any guidance to what I am missing would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` for the `widget-header-div` and `height: 100%` for `.panel` - and you will have same heights for the columns.

If you want to take the widths into consideration in the responsive context, you can make your flexbox *wrap*.

See demo below:

```css
.widget-header-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.widget-header-item .panel {
  height: 100%;
}
.widget-header-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-xs-12 widget-header-div">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 widget-header-item">
    <div class="panel panel-primary pmd-z-depth">
      <div class="panel-heading">Box 1</div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="col-md-12 text-left">
          <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td>Value</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td>Value</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 widget-header-item">
    <div class="panel panel-primary pmd-z-depth">
      <div class="panel-heading">Box 2</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="col-md-12 text-left">
          <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td>Value</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 widget-header-item">
    <div class="panel panel-primary pmd-z-depth">
      <div class="panel-heading">Box 3</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
        <p>Larger body of text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That worked perfect, think I was over complicating it, thank you!

Comment: @JonnyFoley `but I either end up with equal width column which i do not want` no longer the case?

Comment: ohh, I overlooked that, you can *wrap* your `flexbox` and throw in a margin and its fixed, thanks!

Comment: @kukkuz I noticed that you are not using `.row` divs to wrap column definitions.  In my scenario using `.row` and the same css you are proposing does not work.  Don't know why, do you have an idea why? I'm applying widget-header-div to the `.row` div.